# PayPal API, How to manage a no-response scenario?

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal REST API to programmatically transfer amount from one PayPal account to other. Suppose my C#.NET program has initiated transfer via PayPal REST API but got disconnected before receiving any response. How to know whether the initiated transfer has either succeeded or not, later when connectivity is available? So that, I can either confirm transfer or can initiate retry.
Or
How should I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Instant Payment Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to get a notification every time something processes.

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions.

The IPN isn't always timely, you may want to only fall back on this in the case that you get disconnected. I just checked on my last 50 IPN entries, and the log times for them varied from 10 seconds to 5 minutes (averaged 2 minutes) following the transaction on my web server.

To use the IPN, you just need to setup a URL to accept the notifications and that's where you can do any logic needed / save IPN details to the database.

See also:

- [IPN Getting Started](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)
- [IPN Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)
- [Enabling IPN Messaging on your PayPal Account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/)

Comment: To be more precise, suppose program had initiated payout through REST API, got disconnected just before receiving payout_item_id or transaction_id. Meaning, I do not have payout_item_id. How may I fetch status of the particular payout item later in this case?

Comment: @JinuPrince it helps if you put and identifier in the PayPal data that uniquely identifies the item in your system. So when your IPN service processes the transaction, you can use the ID you stored (like in the field `rp_invoice_id`) to look up the transaction in your table, and then you can log the transaction_id provided in the IPN for that item, since the id never came across with the original transaction due to the disconnect.